# Why is ggplot2 missing to plot only one observation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

The first point in the control treatment goes is missing when I plot my graph.

[image: Example]

Its not like it is a missing value or  is zero:

```
dput(as.data.frame(Data[1:4, ]))
structure(list(Treatment = c("Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control"), Day = c(0, 3, 7, 10), mean = c(113.23031277483, 
141.797806551676, 169.677502848003, 241.167084837396), sd = 
c(14.6832678840358, 26.8103881884133, 25.7287049739681, 
35.6514186448066)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

The code used for plotting is:

```
LAK1 <- ggplot(data = Data, aes(x = Day, y = mean, shape = Treatment)) + 
xlim(0, 50) + 
scale_y_continuous(expression ("Leaf area" ~(cm^2)), limits=c(0, 500)) + 
geom_errorbar(data = Data, aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position=position_dodge(0.05)) + 
geom_line(aes(y=mean), position = position_dodge(0.2)) + 
geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 3) + 
theme_classic()
LAK1
```

Comment: With the data you have provided, the plot works as expected - 4 points

Comment: Thanks. I found out the error. I needed to avoid the position = position_dodge(0.2) in geom_line and geom_point.